Looking for advices about proxy
I need to run a Selenium script that requires quick IP rotation—ideally every 30 seconds. Additionally, the script must send 15 requests simultaneously using a multithreaded approach and loop this process 10 times. Could you recommend a reliable proxy service? I am looking for information on good proxy providers.
